# IF column value in dataframe matches list change to another value

Tags: python, list, dataframe

This is quite simple but cannot seem to get it to work. I have four lists, w, x, y, z they match values in the column, change these to another value. For w I want 5, for x I want 1, for Y I want 8 and for Z I want 10

```
w = [6,9,12,30]
x = [4,11,13,14]
Y = [10,16,12,2]
Z = [8,25,24,99]

df:

ID:
6
9
12
30
4 
11
13 
14
10
16
12
2 
8
25
24
99


Wanted output:
5
5
5
5
1
1
1
1
8
8
8
8
10
10
10
10
```

Comment: Could you explain please what is the logic to get 5 for w, 1 for x, etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use np.where for this kind of transformations:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```
df['Output'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(w), 5, 
               np.where(df['ID'].isin(x), 1,
               np.where(df['ID'].isin(y), 8,
               np.where(df['ID'].isin(z), 10,
                  'non-dentified'))))
```

Please also check your formatting of the column ID so the format of the elements in the list is the same as the format of the elements in the column.